# Android must have Expandableview whose id is

Tags: java, android

> Your content must have a ExpandableView whose id is attribute is
>   'android.R.list'

This is the error message I am getting from Logcat. Which is confusing me as my XML is this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">


        <ExpandableListView
                android:id="@+id/list"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
<ExpandableListView   
     android:id="@id/android:list"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
```

[ExpandableListView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ExpandableListActivity.html)

when you define id like this @+id/list means that you define an id name list in your application namespace and you can refer to it by @id/list , but @android:id/list means that you are referring to an id define in the android namespace 
This namespace is the namespace of the framework

Comment: If i do this I get an error in eclipse saying. "error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'id' with value '@id/lsit')"

Comment: in which folder the above file is ?

Comment: layout folder of the res folder

Answer (score 1):

In your XML make this  **android:id="@+id/list"** to this **android:id="@android:id/list"**. It will solve your problem.

See [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ExpandableListActivity.html) link for more help.

Comment: You said u change it.Will u show us what u made changes in ur xml.Ur changed xml file plz